# what php magento setup:static-content:deploy do?

Tags: magento2

i just installed magento 2 on localhost, the logo do not appeared, after i use the command in console `php magento setup:static-content:deploy` , all the static files are generated, why magento 2 need this command to make the static file be generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can refer magento devdocs team documentation for more info about this command,

[Use of Static content deploy in magento 2](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html)

Here given information is useful for beginners.

Comment: It might depend on what [mode](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-modes.html) you're in. The initial mode, `default`, and `developer` both cause static files to be generated when you update thing (e.g., install, upgrade, add products, add images, and so on). Still, I see a lot of suggestions for using this command, so dunno.